# AV Framework front facing camera problems

Tags: ios, video, camera, avfoundation

Hello I am using the AV framework to try to access the front facing camera...

This is my code to do so..

```
+ (AVCaptureDevice *)camera
{
 NSArray *devices = [AVCaptureDevice devicesWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

for (AVCaptureDevice *device in devices) {

    if ([device position] == AVCaptureDevicePositionFront) {
        NSLog(@"Device Position is :%i",device.position);
        return device;

    }

}

return nil;
}
```

The NSLog is telling me I am on position two, however the video being shown on my screen is still from the back... Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
- (AVCaptureDevice *)frontFacingCameraIfAvailable
{
    NSArray *videoDevices = [AVCaptureDevice devicesWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

        AVCaptureDevice *captureDevice = nil;

for (AVCaptureDevice *device in videoDevices) 
{
   if (device.position == AVCaptureDevicePositionFron 
      {
            captureDevice = device;
            break;
        }
    }
//  couldn't find one on the front, so just get the default video device.
    if (!captureDevice)
    {
        captureDevice = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    }
    return captureDevice;
}


AVCaptureDevice *captureDevice = nil;  

if(frontCamera == true){  
    captureDevice = [self frontFacingCameraIfAvailable];  
}

captureInput = [AVCaptureDeviceInput   
            deviceInputWithDevice:captureDevice   
            error:nil];
```

Comment: I am trying to turn on the front facing camera for twenty seconds and half way through play an mp3 file. Both work on there own, just not with each other... For example If I turn the camera on the sound wont play, and If I turn the sound on the camera will stop before the sound is played...

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you starting camera device on different queue? Maybe there is a problem... Try to use some api for sound for example ObjectAL

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, I tell the AVDeivce to begin recording, and then I try to play a systemSoundFile at a certain point but it will not play... I then Tried playing an AVAudioDevice but that just stopped the recording then played a sound.

Comment: As i know there is no possible to record and play sounds at this same time... You can try some Additional libriary for sound, maybe it could help